# self join using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Table Structure

```
Id  your_user_id     my_user_id
1   33              35
2   35              45
3   36              35
4   35              47
5   46              50
```

Expecting

```
Join Record
33
45
36
47
```

I want to get all matches record of id 35 wheather it is in **my_user_id** or in **your_user_id**

Comment: Why nowadays nobody is trying to think a bit but instead looking for ready solutions. Sorry, Amy but that's not the way how you'll learn anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `union` you get this result

```
SELECT B FROM `test2` WHERE C=35
union
SELECT C FROM `test2` WHERE B=35
```